# The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user - Token Authentication

Tags: security, asp.net-identity, owin, csrf, claims-based-identity

my current Authentication process looks like this.  I have a Auth API that generates a token with `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication`.  Once I generate the token inside `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` I set the `Identity.Name` by `identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, context.UserName));`

I want to store my token in a `HttpOnly` cookie, so in `TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)` 
I saved it to a cookie, but I also need to prevent `XSRF` so I generate a `XSRF` token there as well.

```
string cookieToken, formToken;
AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
```

If I look at the current `Identity` context from `OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context`, `Identity.Name` is set, so it should be using this name for the `XSRF` token generation.  **But** `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` is `null`  In my both my APIs I also set

```
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType;
```

Now In my Resource API, I've already taken care of reading the auth token from the cookie and setting it to the `Authorization` header.  That works fine.  I have then created my own `XSRF` Attribute the verify the `XSRF` token.

```
public class ValidateAntiForgery : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            try
            {
                string cookieToken = "";
                string formToken = "";

                IEnumerable<string> tokenHeaders;
                if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("X-XSRF-TOKEN", out tokenHeaders))
                {
                    string[] tokens = tokenHeaders.First().Split(':');
                    if (tokens.Length == 2)
                    {
                        cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                        formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
                    }
                }
                AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

                actionContext.Response = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad Request");
            }
        }
    }
```

Checking the `Identity` in `actionContext`, everything is set and the user is authenticated.  However, `AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);` throws an exception as shown below.  I've looked at the many other examples, but I can't find a solution.

> System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: 'The provided anti-forgery
>   token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current
>   user.'

**EDIT:** So it seems where I generate my `XSRF` token in `TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)`
context.Identity is set with the authenticated `User`, however `HttpContext.Current.User` is `null`.  Even though the `XSRF` tokens generated here are technically valid, I think they are using null from the `HttpContext`.  If I generate the `XSRF` token is a separate `GET` request with [Authorize] so that `HttpContext.Current.User` is not `null`, then the `AntiForgery.Validate` works fine.

I want the `XSRF` token to be returned with the Authentication token, but I'm not sure how to do that.  How do I set `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`?

**EDIT 2:** So I was able to fix the problem using a hacky way.  When I want to generate the `XSRF` token I call the following function.

```
[Authorize]
public string generateXSRFToken(ClaimsIdentity identity)
{
        HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[0]);
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);

        return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
}
```

It works!, but it's ugly, I would like a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem:

```
var returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
    if (returnUrl.IsEmpty()) {
        // Some external login providers always require a return URL value
        returnUrl = Href("~/");
    }
if (WebSecurity.Login(email, password, rememberMe))
        {
            Context.RedirectLocal(returnUrl);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddFormError("The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add at least some explanation on why this lines of coode would fix the problem, so the asker and any other programmer with a similar problem can better understand what's going on.